# doubts regarding word2vec Continuous bag-of-words (CBOW)

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

[image]

For the CBOW model, the INPUT words are feed into the training model simultaneously or one by one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> For the CBOW model, the INPUT words are feed into the training model simultaneously or one by one?

The input to CBOW model is the preceding and following words of the current word. The output of the neural network will be the current word. Hence you can think of the task as "predicting the word given its context".

So, the context words or input words (according to your question) are feed to the network simultaneously during training.

Comment: So the word vector matrix is between input and hidden layer. In the case of CBOW, do we have many matrices between input and hidden layer, as shown in the figure of  @Max Weinzierl ?

Comment: @derek no, there is one matrix only. each row in the matrix is associated with one word. each row is typically a one hot encoding representation of one word.

Answer (score 1):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2738.pdf) has a great explanation of how Word2Vec operates both for CBOW and Skip-Gram.

The words are fed in simultaneously as one-hot encoded vectors. Then the one-hot representations are multiplied by the weight matrix (which doubles up as the word embedding matrix in the Word2Vec architecture). This multiplication boils down to extracting a single row from W - the row corresponding to the word embedding in question.

The hidden layer is then just an aggregation (average in most cases) of each of the word embeddings extracted using the one-hot encoded inputs.

[image: Word2Vec CBOW Model]

Answer (score -1):

Here is a more descriptive diagram of the word2vec Continuous bag-of-words (CBOW)
[image: word2vec Continuous bag-of-words (CBOW)]

These words X_1 to X_c are fed in simultaneously during training.

Source: https://iksinc.wordpress.com/tag/continuous-bag-of-words-cbow/

Paper discussing it further: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~ronxin/pdf/w2vexp.pdf

Comment: so the input is c x V matrix? c is the number of context words. V is vocabulary size.

Comment: in your graph, are all the input matrices the same?

Comment: In my graph the input matrices are all different context words to be used for the CBOW model. c x V is correct if you are encoding your words in that vector format. See the sources I provided for more specific information on implementation.

Comment: From my understanding of word2vec, each word can only have a word vector. But in the given source, each word is having a "word matrix". Am I missing anything?

Comment: Could you explain where it describes a "word matrix"?

Comment: OK. Let me one step back.  What is the word vector of X1 in your figure?

Comment: It is the word vector for a specific context word produced by word2vec.

Comment: The final goal of word2vec is to generate a look-up table such that each word can find its word vector from the look-up table. My question is in your figure, where is the look-up table?

Comment: I think you are confused about the purpose of Continuous bag-of-words models. I recommend you read through the sources I provided to get a better understanding of their purpose.

Comment: The goal of word2vec is to generate word vectors (look-up table) for all the unique words in the given corpus. word2vec employs two methods/algorithms: CBOW and skip-gram, both of which can generate a lookup table (input matrix) between input and hidden layer.

Comment: I think the figure is confused. In the original blog, someone also point it out.
The author mention it in blog.
` [An alert reader pointed that the figure below might lead some readers to think that CBOW learning uses several input matrices. It is not so. It is the same matrix, WI, that is receiving multiple input vectors representing different context words]`